# Navigate between windows in a simple quiz app

Tags: java

I have to make a simple quiz application in JAVA and I have no idea on how to navigate between windows, for example, how to go to the next question or how to go back. I have a single question per window. Can you give me an idea on how to navigate? Should I use repaint() or a CardLayout or something else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes CardLayout can be a good idea for this purpose, if you need some example take a look at the [oracle how to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Yes yes, I am aware oh how to use CardLayout, but I was thinking of a more elegant way to implement it, using BACK and NEXT buttons. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a more elegant way? It cause you trouble to have to make a Panel for each questions?

Answer (score 1):

If the quiz is multiple choice, you have other options: change the data that the questions (probably JRadioButtons) displays. Otherwise, I vote for a CardLayout. Also, if you want the user to be able to easily go back to other questions, you could display them all as JPanels in a GridLayout using JPanel held by a JScrollPane.